# Having a problem moving my google cloud app to production

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have some file on the google cloud storage which am downloading just fine on my localhost but when i upload the script to cpanel i get errors. below is the code am using. i get this error whenever i run the code:
Warning:  putenv() has been disabled for security reasons

```
session_start();
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../92085350b1a.json");
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
// Imports the Cloud Storage client library.
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;


function download_object($file)
{
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $storage->registerStreamWrapper();
    $name = "../files/".time().".epub";
    if(file_put_contents($name,file_get_contents("url/".$file.".epub"))){
        $_SESSION['book']=explode("/",$name)[2];
        echo 'read';
    }else{
        echo "book not found";
    }
}

$el = explode("/",$_POST['url']);
$name = explode(".",$el[1]);
download_object($name[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this line of code:

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../92085350b1a.json");
```

Since your environment does not allow modifying the environment, specify the credentials when creating the Google Cloud Storage Client.

Change this line:

```
$storage = new StorageClient();
```

To this:

```
$storage = new StorageClient(['keyFilePath' => '../92085350b1a.json']);
```

Suggestion. Do not use relative paths such as **../92085350b1a.json**. Instead, use absolution paths if your environment supports that.